# Heroku timing out when using sequelize

Tags: node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

As of yesterday (04/24/20) Heroku bumped the standard node version to v14. If you are using sequelize this can cause any call to sequelize to hang without an error until heroku times out.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by downgrading to v13 of node.

add:

```
"engine": { "node": 13.x.x }
```

to your package.json and heroku will respect this version.

The issue is being [tracked here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12158)